# vb.net convert string to date

Tags: vb.net, datetime

how do i convert the string

30.10.2009   in date? 
(dd.mm.yyyy)

thanks :>

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) function:

```
Dim DateStr = "30.10.2009"
Dim Dt As DateTime
If DateTime.TryParseExact(DateStr, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, Dt) Then
    ' The date was successfully parsed => use the Dt variable
End If
```

Comment: it says, that  "CultureInfo" and "DateTimeStyles" is not declared- do i have to include something?

Comment: Yes, the `System.Globalization` namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx):

```
Dim culture as CultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US")
Dim date as DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("30.10.2009", "dd.MM.yyyy", culture)
```

See [custom datetime format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) on MSDN.

If you are not sure that the format is exactly as mentioned, you can use [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) to avoid an exception being thrown.