# How translate string to date in .NET

Tags: vb.net

I followed suggestion from  [vb.net convert string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607622/vb-net-convert-string-to-date)  .  But, it did not work.

the code is as follows:

```
    Dim Dt As DateTime
    If DateTime.TryParse("Thu, 09 Dec 2010 16:03:24 EST", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, Dt) Then
        MessageBox.Show(Dt)
    End If
```

Can anyone solve this for me?  I need to have date populated in the format of "yyyy-mm-dd hh24-mi-ss".

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: this answer was written for a previous revision of the question which had the following code:**

```
Dim Dt As DateTime
If DateTime.TryParseExact("Thu, 09 Dec 2010 16:03:24 EST", "dd.MM.yyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, Dt) Then
    MessageBox.Show(Dt)
End If
```

---

The format string that [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) takes as it's second parameter specifies the format of the date in the string passed as the first.

In your case the format string is specifying that the date will be of the format "09.12.2010" for example - just the day, moth and year. However, as the string **isn't in that format** it won't parse. If you'd just used `ParseExact` it would have raised an exception.

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx) for the variant of `TryParseExact` that takes an array of possible format strings has more examples, but non match your format exactly, but working with the format strings used to convert `DateTime` to `string` you probably want something like this:

```
"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ???"
```

but I can't find what you'd need instead of "???" to match the "time zone as string". You might have to do some string manipulation to remove this before calling `TryParse` or `TryParseExact`.

Comment: Sorry.  My bad.  I should have been clear.  First of all, the code what I posted does not parse at all.

Comment: @user203687 - it won't as the date time string doesn't match the format string. I obviously didn't make that clear.

Comment: oh. Ok. But Chris, I am unable to parse the following at least:        Dim Dt As DateTime
        If DateTime.TryParse("Thu, 09 Dec 2010 16:03:24 EST", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, Dt) Then
            MessageBox.Show(Dt)
        End If

Comment: @user203687 - I think it's the time zone name that's causing the problem. I haven't found the format specifier for this yet.

Comment: @user203687 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-timezone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc

Answer (score 0):

this should get you on the right path:

```
    Dim dt As DateTime
    dt = Now
    TextBox1.Text = Format(dt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Sorry.  My bad.  I should have been clear.  First of all, the code what I posted does not parse at all.

Comment: Isn't your goal "have date populated in the format of "yyyy-mm-dd hh24-mi-ss""

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace the timezone with the timezone offset.
Same question as [Parse DateTime with time zone of form PST/CEST/UTC/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-timezone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
    TextBox1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(698).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

    DateTime DOB;
    string[] formatsDOB = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy" };
    DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDateofBirth.Text, formatsDOB, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DOB);
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. You might want to consider adding some text to your answer describing what your code does as this will prove beneficial to those completely unfamiliar with the language. Code-only answers are generally not encouraged - a discussion of this can be found [here at meta-stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques).